# Isotope filtering by class

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I've set up Isotope to filter some posts on my wordpress page. Right now the animation is working fine, and the classes/data-filters are named the same thing, but I can't seem to get it to work. The Show all button works great, but for the other categories, all the posts disappear instead of the ones with the correct class names staying. I've tried logging all my js variables and they appear to be correct as far as I understand. Anyone know why this isn't working?

http://codepen.io/kathryncrawford/pen/WwevaG

JS

```
$(function ($) {

var $container = $('.js-grid'); //The class for the list with all the case studies
$container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
    itemSelector : '.js-case-item',
    layoutMode : 'vertical'
});

//Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from the others
var $optionSets = $('.js-filter-container'),
$optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

$optionLinks.click(function(){
var $this = $(this);
// don't proceed if already selected
if ( $this.hasClass('js-selected') ) {
  return false;
}
$optionSets.find('.js-selected').removeClass('js-selected');
$this.addClass('js-selected');

//When an item is clicked, sort the items.
var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$container.isotope({ filter: selector });

});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector variable seems to be trying to filter a simple string.

Example:

```
var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
console.log(selector) //output: 'app_dev'
```

You need to add a " . " to tell the isotope it's a class:

```
var selector = '.' + $(this).attr('data-filter');
console.log(selector) //output: '.app_dev'
```

Comment: Ugh, I knew it had to be something simple! Thanks!

Comment: @KathrynCrawford I have to tell you that my solution will cause the Show All button to stop working. Try to use a conditional statement to see if `$(this).attr('data-filter') == "*"` so you don't add the dot in that case. Also using `$(this).data('filter');` woul be a little cleaner.

Comment: Oh cool, thanks! I added that if statement and the all filter works great as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter links want a css-style definition of the class to filter on.

Rather than `data-filter="app_dev"`, you need `data-filter=".app_dev"`.

One of your links as an better example:

`<a class="l-case-studies-filter-link || s-case-studies-filter-link || s-case-studies-filter-link-1 || s-link-no-underline || js-filter" rel="bookmark" data-filter="app_dev">App Dev</a>`

should be

`<a class="l-case-studies-filter-link || s-case-studies-filter-link || s-case-studies-filter-link-1 || s-link-no-underline || js-filter" rel="bookmark" data-filter=".app_dev">App Dev</a>`